# Purple Comet Question on finding a three-digit integer $n$ satisfying $(n - 3)(n - 5) = 6z^2$ for a positive integer $z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So there was one problem on the Purple Comet, which I mostly solved up to one point:

> Find a three-digit positive integer $n$ and a positive integer $z$ that satisfy the equation $(n-3)(n-5)=6z^2$.

The answer is $n = 489$, but how do I get it from the equation?

I tried to solve like this:

Let’s say $n-3$ is $p+2$, and $n-5$ is $p$:

$$p(p+2)=6z^2$$

THEN

$$(p+1)^2=6z^2+1$$

I found that $z$ can be $2$, or $20$, when I tried.

(P.S. $n$ has to be a $3$ digit number that follows that rule.)

Hope to get some help! THANKS!

Comment: The question could use some clarification.  Are you searching for a three-digit positive integer $n$ that satisfies the equation $(n - 3)(n - 5) = 6z^2$ for some positive integer $z$?  Also, is $N = n$ and $Z = z$?

Comment: Yes and yes. They are.

Comment: It's Purple Comet, so you write a computer program.

Comment: I’m sorry, WHAT?